# Finding First, second, and third place in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to think of how to pull data from an array of times within the cells of a spreadsheet then match the runners with their position. Please use google apps script code and nothing else. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A good question includes some code, and an explanation of what you have tried.  You are basically asking someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script:

```
function runnerPosition()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('RunnerPosition');
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  rng.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
}
```

Here's what the spreadsheet looks like before sorting:
[image]

Here's what the spreadsheet looks like after sorting:[image]